# Working with AWS ec2 for deploying React+Node app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy a full stack application with react and nodejs on aws ec2. I've followed this tutorial here : https://medium.com/@balghazi/deploying-react-node-js-application-to-amazon-ec2-instance-a89140ab6aab

But, at last the author says to access your webpage you need to open public dns at port 3000 which we had set in server.js client file and since I'm working on ec2 for the first time I have no idea how to open the public dns at 3000 port. Can somebody help me out here?

Code used is in the medium link above. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The medium post says that you should open port 3000 in [security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#WorkingWithSecurityGroups) which is used by your instance.

A link to the AWS offical instructions on how to do it is below:

- [Adding, removing, and updating rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#AddRemoveRules)

Comment: I've added both ports (3000 and 4000) in security groups as custom TCP but when I open my public dns it won't work. Do I have to mention port in the url itself somewhere?

Comment: @SuryaMahla Yes. Without port, dns will use a default 80 port.

Comment: where in the URL do I need to mention the port? 
http://ec2-0-00-000-00.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ 
I have the port in my security group already as inbound rules custom TCP.

Comment: @SuryaMahla ` ec2-0-00-000-00.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000` or `:4000`. The same goes when using IP address.

Comment: Thank you. It worked but another thing I want to ask is what if i need it to run it on just the address without the port number. The client is running on port 3000 in server.js file. Will making it process.env.PORT work?

Comment: @SuryaMahla Then your app must be listening on port 80 for http, or for 443 for https. Anyway, if you happy with the answer it acceptance would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213670/discussion-between-surya-mahla-and-marcin).